# Estoy tratando de hacer un login con asp.net mvc y entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, login

Estoy haciendo un login pero en el controlador no me esta tomando los valores que estoy ingresando en los campos del formulario.

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Usuarios log)
    {
        
        var usuario= db.Usuarios.Where(x => x.UsuNombre==log.UsuNombre && x.UsuPass==log.UsuPass).FirstOrDefault();

        if (usuario != null)
        {

            return RedirectToAction("Dashboard");
        }
        else
        {

            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Estas mostrando solamente el POST, pero para comprender mejor sería bueno que muestres la llamada (GET) a Index()

Comment: Qué significa: "no me esta tomando los valores"? Te llega null el objeto `log` al controlador? Cómo mandas esos datos? Mediante un `<form />`? A través de `ajax`? Por favor, edita tu pregunta y añade todos los detalles que creass

Comment: los toma como null, los estoy enviando a traves de un **@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))**

Comment: Jaiver, agregá el código de la vista y también de la llamada al Index() pero por GET. Así tenemos el circuito completo y lo podemos analizar.